# How to read a docx file using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, view, electron, docx

As the title above. Now I am making an electron app that has function is show content of a docx file which includes words and images.
Do anyone know a nodejs library to do that?

Comment: You're getting down votes and close votes as StackOverflow is not supposed to be used for recommendations. Better would be to have done the same web search I did, tried one or two of the alternatives, then come back with specific questions if you hit problems with them.

Comment: `Mammoth https://github.com/mwilliamson/mammoth.js` will surely help you.

Answer (score 8):

I've had this question a few times (so would love to hear what you end up using).

We've used Textract (https://www.npmjs.com/package/textract) (NB. there is a Python package, and an AWS service, with the same name; which are both unrelated.) It is just getting the plain text out. It has struggled with some formats, especially PDF. If you also want images and formatting, this is not really what you want.

A quick Google found this list:
https://libraries.io/search?keywords=docx&languages=JavaScript

Mammoth (https://github.com/mwilliamson/mammoth.js) is actively developed. Take note of the limitations it describes. However the fact that it produces HTML will make your display in an Electron app much easier.

LibreOffice-convert (https://github.com/elwerene/libreoffice-convert) is new to me since I last searched. Leveraging LibreOffice sounds like an intelligent thing to do. It is just a simple wrapper around the headless mode of LibreOffice. The dependencies make it less than ideal for an Electron app.

Along the same lines, you could try a wrapper for pandoc (https://github.com/eshinn/node-pandoc)

Comment: https://github.com/mwilliamson/mammoth.js can be a good option for basic conversion of docx to HTML.

Answer (score 2):

```
const {DOMParser} = require('xmldom');
const xpath  = require("xpath");
const JsZip = require("jszip");
const fs = require("fs");

//need to add declare:
let docxInputPath = ""; 
let strOutputPath = "";

// Read the docx internal xdocument
let wSelect = xpath.useNamespaces({"w": "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"});
let docxFile = fs.readFileSync(docxInputPath);
await JsZip.loadAsync(docxFile).then(async (zip) => {
    await zip.file('word/document.xml').async("string").then(docx_str =>  
    {
        let docx = new DOMParser().parseFromString(docx_str);
        let outputString = "";
        let paragraphElements = this.wSelect("//w:p",docx);
        paragraphElements.forEach(paragraphElement => 
        {
            let textElements = this.wSelect(".//w:t",paragraphElement);
            textElements.forEach(textElement => outputString += textElement.textContent);
            if(textElements.length > 0)
                outputString += "\n";
        });
        fs.writeFileSync(strOutputPath,outputString);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, this is very unclear. Can you add links, or some citations, so others can confirm that your code addresses the question? Also, please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I will try to upate it with more details, the idea of that code is that a docx file holding inside an xml document that for some problems can be extracted in this simple way i wrote...

Comment: This is a nice low-level approach, but real-world docx files will be using more than just document.xml, and more than just paragraph elements, which is where you will start to crave a good library to help you.

Answer (score 0):

**JUL 2021**

If you only want to work with DOCX or plain text you can use **textract-lite**

More document types (10+) available in **textract**

```
yarn add @nosferatu500/textract
```

https://github.com/nosferatu500/textract

```
yarn add @nosferatu500/textract-lite
```

https://github.com/nosferatu500/textract-lite

**Note:**
I forked and updated deps when various CVE was found. I also cut out all the functionality for the light version and left only support for docx and txt

Comment: You should mention that you are the author of this. Or, as it is a branch of the original textract, it'd be good to explain what is different (and if nothing significant, then linking to https://github.com/dbashford/textract would be better).